fullcalendar timeline width of event not exact as event duration
While using month timeline view, event durations which are not for full day (e.g 4 hours) are showed as full day, until you switch view to week or day.
How it is possible that in timeline event width should be as exact duration as duration in month view.
Ref: https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=001
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineTenDay,resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineYear'
    },
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    scrollTime: '08:00',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    views: {
        resourceTimelineDay: {
            buttonText: ':15 slots',
            slotDuration: '00:15'
        },
        resourceTimelineTenDay: {
            type: 'resourceTimeline',
            duration: { days: 10 },
            buttonText: '10 days'
        }
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline'
});

Thank you.
Events take full block in of day event duration is not set to full day.

Your codepen link doesn't work. That's just a link to an empty one. Please [edit] your question to link to a valid, saved codepen, if you want to provide us with a demonstration of the problem. Or you can use a runnable code snippet directly within your question.

Anyway... event durations which are not for full day (e.g 4 hours) are showed as full day, until you switch view to week or day...yes, that's how it works. The smallest visible unit of time represented on that view is 1 day, so of course the calendar cannot subdivide it further. The purpose is to represent a large window of time in a small space. The price of that is a loss of small-scale detail. Therefore if you want more detail you have to use the week or day views to get exact information...

(P.S. If you change the slotDuration of that view to "24 hours" instead of "1 day" then you get a different result - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/RwXyoKZ . Maybe that's what will help you - but you'll probably want to tidy up the slot label formatting as per your requirements. You can check the documentation for how to do that.)

Thank you for your advise, its converting to the slots but width of the event is still not as compared to actual time in slot.

It gives as close an approximation as it can, in the small space available (https://imgur.com/a/MdgY92G). This is a tradeoff between the user experience of looking at a big area of time, and providing lots of detail. The reason those week and day views exist is to allow you to see the info in more detail, with more space available. The tradeoff is you can see less days at once. If you look at a "month" view in the calendar on your phone you will see the same issue - the more days are visible at once, the less detail you can see. I don't know what else you are expecting? Be realistic.
